# How feasible is it for a high school student to explore nonlinear dynamical systems/chaos theory in a research paper?

Tags: soft-question, chaos-theory

I have been tasked to write a maths essay on a topic of my choice. One of the areas that seems appealing is chaos theory and possibly nonlinear dynamical systems as a whole. However, what I wonder is whether the maths might be too complicated.

The plan was to try to look at bits of maths where order came out of chaos, such as Ramsey Numbers, a more advanced look at probability which strays away from combinatorics, or catastrophes.

Is this at all possible, given time? If so, could anyone point me towards a few sources which go over the maths of the above topics, for neither have I found any nor do I want just a superficial knowledge of the matters.

Comment: This is a fine idea and easy to experiment with a calculator. You may begin studying iterations with the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map). The [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set) and fractals may be part of the trip too.  Good luck,

Comment: A rather accessible book is Saupe, Jürgens and Peitgen's ["Chaos and Fractals"](https://books.google.com/books?id=rZTkBwAAQBAJ) (a rather thick book... anyway you'll have to extract your topics of choice!) .

Comment: Yes! You can definitely do it! It is a very rewarding topic to research. As for references, this book gives you some nice insights without much formalization (knowing a bit about derivatives is enough to get you through half of the book): Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical sistems - Robert L. Devaney. Hope it helps!

Comment: The time you waste when using a calculator for this is better invested by learning some elementary programming (e.g., Python). CC @RaymondManzoni

Comment: I highly recommend Steven Strogatzs' book "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos". He also has [course lectures online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ycJEoqmQvwg&list=PLbN57C5Zdl6j_qJA-pARJnKsmROzPnO9V) which follow the book.